# Prestashop BLOCK CMS INFO

Tags: module, content-management-system, prestashop

I would like to create the extra custom block, I tried to follow the information provided by official website of prestashop (http://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-1-6-x-how-to-work-with-custom-cms-block.html#gref) , neverthelesse my version is lacking the blockcmsinfo.tpl file (I use custom prestashop template)

Any idea how i shall proceede to add this extra block?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a custom theme, then you will find the `blockcmsinfo.tpl` file under `/modules/blockcmsinfo/` directory. You can copy this file to `/themes/yourtheme/modules/blockcmsinfo/` and edit it.